# Javascript Regex to match JSDoc string parameter description

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pcre

Given a JSDoc string, for example:

`*\n * This is a doc string\n * @param withArg description of withArg\n * @param withArg2 description of withArg2 \n`

I am trying to extract the argument names and description in an app running on Node 8.

This regex: `/@param(\s?\w*)(.*?)\\n/` seems to work in a Regex editor. See 
https://regex101.com/r/uJz0Km/2/.

But when ran like this:

```
const matchParamsAndDescriptionRegex = /@param(\s?\w*)(.*?)\\n/g;
const matches = matchParamsAndDescriptionRegex.exec(value);
```

it returns `null`. Can you guys spot what's wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: So you must have regular LF symbols in your original string, not 2 char sequences of ``\`` and `n`. Try just  `/@param\s*\w*(.*)/g` in the *code* ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/xaX8n6/3)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, indeed that's a LF issue. How ever when I try your regex I am only matching the first param. Do you have any suggestion to make this workf for all params and different carriage return styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have regular LF symbols in your original string, not two-char sequences of `\` and `n`.

Use

```
/@param\s*\w*(.*)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xaX8n6/4) where

- `@param` - matches `@param`
- `\s*\w*` - matches 0+ whitespaces and then 0+ word chars
- `(.*)` - captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars.

Sample JS demo:

```js
var s = "*\n * This is a doc string\n * @param withArg description of withArg\n * @param withArg2 description of withArg2 \n"
var rx = /@param\s*\w*(.*)/g;
var res=[], m;
while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push(m[1].trim());
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I am. The new post I've made was about getting the "description" part of the JS DOC. Your code works fine to grab the @params part